# How do I run a script calling the system function in Linux with C programming?

Tags: c, linux

I have created a script that takes a file(FiletoModify.txt) and copy line by line everything it contains to a new txt file which I called it output.txt.My problem is that I want to call system to do the following in my code but it doesn't work.I'm a new in C programming and I'm making it clear that I can't see my mistake and I really need some help.Thank you

My code in my C program:

```
system("cd Desktop; chmod +x script.sh ; ./script.sh");
```

Here's the script code:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    while IFS= read -r line
    do
    echo "$line"
    echo -e "$line\n" >>output.txt

    done <"FiletoModify"
```

Comment: Even if it otherwise worked, this wouldn't copy your file faithfully -- it would convert `\t` to a tab character, for instance, or `\n` to an extra newline. Don't use `echo -e` (which is also non-POSIX); `printf '%s\n' "$line"` is your friend.

Comment: Beyond that... well, _why_ use `system()` at all? You can call `chdir()`, `chmod()`, etc., from C -- which is faster and doesn't open you up to bugs like shellshock.

Comment: I only know the system function.I have also stored this script in my desktop.What else do you suggest me to do?.....If I use chmod() how can I pass the arguments?

Comment: Also, is the `//` in your original code? For a shebang to work, the `#!` need to be the literal first two characters of the file; you can't have anything else before them.

Comment: What directory are you executing the C program in? Does it contain the directory `Desktop`?

Comment: Mr Charles Duffy I had seen a similar code here (in Stackoverflow) and I though it was OK ...but I will try to do it your way

Comment: @tel, since it's a `;` rather than a `&&`, the code would proceed to try to chmod and execute the script even if no `Desktop` directory existed and the earlier `cd` failed. Which is arguably a bug, but means that there are two directories, rather than one, from which this code can be executed.

Comment: tel my code is in Desktop....everything a use(including files) is in Desktop!

Comment: What is the actual error message that you're getting?

Comment: Guys I'm so confused....can someone help me do it correctly from scratch?

Comment: tel sh: 1: cd: can't cd to Desktop
this is what terminal says!!!

Comment: Might try a full path. And make sure you have permissions for everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so from your error message your problem is with the `cd Desktop;` part of your C program. Two possible fixes:

1. Delete `cd Desktop;` from your `system` call.
2. Run your C executable from a directory one level above `Desktop` (i.e. the directory which contains `Desktop`).

Comment: sh: 1: ./script.sh: not found I did it but this is what a got from terminal!

Comment: My previous comment was incorrect. Assuming that you're now running your C executable from one level above Desktop, make sure that there actually is a shell script named script.sh in your Desktop directory. The error you're getting would indicate that currently there isn't.

Comment: Always believe your error messages. Try to address the problem they describe (they're usually accurate, if a bit stupid and hard to understand). Even if your program doesn't run, if your error message changes consider this to be progress.

Comment: I have saved everything in Desktop but I haven't found a solution yet

Comment: Your link points to *my* dropbox. You'll need to right click on your code and select "Copy public link" in order to get the correct link.

Comment: So I think I know your problem. You weren't supposed to use both of the solutions that I posted. It was an either/or kind of deal.
So replace the "Desktop" part in your system call, and then still run the executable from the directory one level above Desktop.